# Does CnosDB support the OpenTSDB write API?

Tags: cnosdb

My project originally used OpenTSDB to store data in a time series database, and now I want to migrate to CnosDB. However, I noticed that the CnosDB documentation does not mention the OpenTSDB write API. So, I would like to know if CnosDB supports the OpenTSDB write API.